# How do I get Google Now's Package Tracking to Work?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, google-now, 4.2-jelly-bean

In Google Search settings -> Google Now, I have "Show cards based on Gmail" checked. "Packages" is on, and the description says "when an order confirmation email is delivered for an online purchase"

Since turning that on, I've used mutt's bounce feature to deliver two Amazon shipping notices to my gmail account. The email notifications showed up on my phone, but (even a day later) I still haven't been able to get the Google Now package tracking card to show.

How do I get it to work?

Here's the message in gmail:

[image: Amazon email showing in gmail]

### Update

I'm now on Android 4.2, and (after the 4.2 upgrade) received an email from the Google Play store with a tracking number this morning. Still no delivery status card from Google Now. Will check the Amazon soon again, too (once they ship me something).

### Nexus 10

I've got a Nexus 10 as well now (also running Android 4.2, stock, not even rooted), and package tracking also doesn't seem to work there, either.

Comment: I have the same problem, running Jelly Bean on SGS3 (Tmobile). I ordered an item from Amazon, Google Now created a card for it without a problem. Item was delivered 4 days ago (UPS). Google Now still shows a shipping card, but when I click on the card it opens UPS site showing delivery confirmation. Why doesn't Google Now card update to show delivery and get rid of the card? How do I get rid of this card? Kind of annoying that it comes up every day for an already delivered package.

Comment: @Vanderberg well, now I know where all my missing Google Now cards are: you have them. Maybe we can arrange a trade... :-/

Answer (score -1):

To use those new feature when informations are being pulled from gmail you are going to need the new gmail app there is a flashable zip on xda-developers but its reporting to break some stuff so your best bet is to wait a week or so to get the Jellybean update from google.

Comment: That's not true. I don't have the new version of the Gmail app and package tracking is working just fine for me on my galaxy nexus and nexus 7.

Comment: I think I had the new gmail app (at least, there was a new version in Play store recently). And now of course I have it as part of Android 4.2. Still no luck (see question update)

Comment: I don't think package tracking in Google Now is dependent on the Gmail app version on your phone! This type of data extraction is done server-side and not on the phone.